# Oozie spark action with kerberos

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, kerberos, oozie

Unable to schedule oozie spark action with Kerberos cluster.

```
<workflow-app name="Spark Test" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
  <credentials>
    <credential name="hiveCredentials" type="hcat">
      <property>
        <name>hcat.metastore.uri</name>
        <value>${hcatMetastoreURI}</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>hcat.metastore.principal</name>
        <value>${hcatPrincipal}</value>
      </property>
    </credential>
  </credentials>
    <start to="spark-4c1d"/>
    <kill name="Kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <action name="spark-4c1d" cred="hiveCredentials">
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <job-xml>/user/hive-site.xml</job-xml>
                <configuration>
                    <property>
                        <name>oozie.action.sharelib.for.spark</name>
                        <value>spark</value>
                    </property>
                </configuration>
            <master>yarn</master>
            <mode>cluster</mode>
            <name>MySpark</name>
              <class>com.test.testMain</class>
            <jar>${nameNode}/user/test/test-20.0.0.jar</jar>
              <spark-opts>
                --conf spark.default.parallelism=16
                --conf spark.driver.cores=1
                --conf spark.driver.memory=1g
                --conf spark.executor.cores=2
                --conf spark.executor.instances=1
                --conf spark.executor.memory=1g
                --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=16
                --conf spark.sql.window.partitions=16
                --conf spark.hadoop.hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true
                --conf spark.hadoop.hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict
                --conf spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet=false
                --conf spark.hadoop.fs.hdfs.impl.disable.cache=true
                --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=false
                --conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1
                --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-driver.properties -Dhdfs.url=${nameNode}"
                --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-executor.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=parquet.logging.properties"
                --files /etc/hive/conf.cloudera.hive/hive-site.xml
                --jars ${nameNode}/user/test/lib/*
            </spark-opts>
        </spark>
        <ok to="End"/>
        <error to="Kill"/>
    </action>
    <end name="End"/>
</workflow-app>
```

When I try to run the oozie action it fails with the following error.

```
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user

at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.promptForPass(Krb5LoginModule.java:901)
at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:764)
at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:618)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$HadoopLoginContext.login(UserGroupInformation.java:2070)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doSubjectLogin(UserGroupInformation.java:1982)
... 35 more
Failing Oozie Launcher, failure to login: for principal: hdfs javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user
```

The same workflow works fine if I use spark-submit inside a shell script with a  custom keytab and principal as given in this link https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/sg_spark_auth.html. 
Please suggest if I am missing anything

Comment: You try to run something as `hdfs` -- not sure if it's the Oozie service (trying to impersonate a user account) ou the user account (being impersonated). Either the Oozie service is not correctly kerberized with its own `oozie` principal and the appropriate config of that "proxy account" in `core-site.xml`; or you are trying to use a black-listed privileged account to run an Action, instead of a regular user account. Lousy setup in either case

Comment: I have been using other actions such as hive, java, shell scripts etc with credentials. All other actions work fine except spark. I made sure that the user is not present in black-listed.

Comment: facing exactly the same issue, did you figure out the problem?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Still I am facing the same issue.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-29082 this issue is resolved by cloudera. I guess this fix is available in higher versions.

Comment: I had a discussion with Cloudera support about the issue, they have confirmed that this is a known issue in Spark version shipped in Cloudera CDH 6.2.1, CDH 6.3.1, CDH 6.3.2 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-29082 , the fix is available in CDH 6.3.3. We had to upgrade our Cloudera cluster and everything is running smoothly.

Comment: It might help someone who cannot upgrade their version and would like to use spark action itself. Add this configuration in  spark action, to successfully run the workflow      --keytab
                spark.keytab
                --principal
                ${{principal}  
                {{- end }}  configuration